# I get missings POST params in my php IPN callback after iPhone SDK payment

Tags: php, ios, callback, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal SDK 1.6 for iOS.
I have a IPN callback php script and When I test from IPN Paypal Simulator it works fine (Payment verified) And when I test from an iPhone payment I have some missing POST parameters.

**Edit : Code**

```
<?php
// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
//"ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use: 
     $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use:
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

$mail_From = "From: me@mybiz.com";
$mail_To = "testenter code here@gmail.com";
$mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);


}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

$mail_From = "From: me@mybiz.com";
$mail_To = "test@gmail.com";
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: What are the missing POST params?

Comment: Some mising params like :

payment_status
payer_status
first_name
last_name
payer_email
payer_id
custom
txn_id
mc_gross

Answer (score 1):

The IPN from the sandbox simulates an Express Checkout transaction, which is a different type of transaction than what you get from using the Mobile Payments Library.

One item that you are probably getting is the PayKey. With the PayKey you can make a second API call to the PaymentDetails API, which should yield the rest of the information you're looking for.

Ref: [Payment Details API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/paymentdetails-api-operation)

Answer (score 0):

I change the request method with curl and now my script work fine:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
```